Unable to find button via uiatuomator android benchmarking for a multimodular project
I have a multimodular project and I want to test benchmarking
These are my modules

:app [variant : debug, release ; flavors: prod, stage] [globalPackageName]
:presentation [loginPackageName]
:data
:domain
:common
:benchmark (macro)

:benchmark modules build.gradle.kts
import com.android.build.api.dsl.ManagedVirtualDevice

@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION") // TODO: Remove once KTIJ-19369 is fixed
plugins {
    id("com.android.test")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    alias(libs.plugins.baselineprofile.plugin)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.ola.benchmark"
    compileSdk = 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments["androidx.benchmark.suppressErrors"] =
            "EMULATOR,DEBUGGABLE"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    testOptions.managedDevices.devices {
        create<ManagedVirtualDevice>("pixel2api34") {
            device = "Pixel 2"
            apiLevel = 34
            systemImageSource = "aosp-atd"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        // This benchmark buildType is used for benchmarking, and should function like your
        // release build (for example, with minification on). It"s signed with a debug key
        // for easy local/CI testing.
        create("benchmark") {
            isDebuggable = false
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
            matchingFallbacks.add("release")
            proguardFiles("benchmark-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    targetProjectPath = ":app"
    experimentalProperties["android.experimental.self-instrumenting"] = true
}

androidComponents {
    beforeVariants {
        it.enable = it.buildType == "benchmark"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.test.ext.junit)
    implementation(libs.espresso.core)
    implementation(libs.androidx.runner)
    implementation(libs.androidx.junit.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.core)
    implementation(libs.uiautomator)
    implementation(libs.junit.jupiter.api)

    implementation(libs.courutinesTest)
    implementation(libs.benchmark.macro.junit4)
    implementation(libs.profileInstaller)

    implementation(libs.retrofit)
    implementation(libs.retrofit.gson.converter)
    implementation(libs.okhttp)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.livedata)
    implementation(libs.coroutinesCore)
    implementation(libs.coroutinesAndroid)
}

baselineProfile {
    // This specifies the managed devices to use that you run the tests on.
    managedDevices += "pixel2Api34"

    // Don't use a connected device but rely on a GMD for consistency between local and CI builds.
    useConnectedDevices = false

}

tasks.register<Exec>("generateBaselineProfiles") {
    commandLine(
        ".././gradlew",
        "allDevicesBenchmarkAndroidTest",
        "--rerun-tasks",
        "-P",
        "android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.benchmark.BaselineProfileGenerator",
    )
}

tasks.register<Exec>("installBaselineProfiles") {
    dependsOn("generateBaselineProfiles")
    doLast {
        commandLine(
            "cp",
            "-R",
            "$rootDir/benchmark/build/outputs/managed_device_android_test_additional_output/benchmark/pixel2api34/BaselineProfileGenerator_generateBaselineProfile-baseline-prof.txt",
            "$rootDir/app/src/main/baseline-prof.txt"
        )
        commandLine(
            "cp",
            "-R",
            "$rootDir/benchmark/build/outputs/managed_device_android_test_additional_output/benchmark/pixel2api34/BaselineProfileGenerator_generateBaselineProfile-startup-prof.txt",
            "$rootDir/app/src/main/startup-prof.txt"
        )
    }
}

inside :benchmark module I created a file ExampleTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleStartupBenchmark {
    @get:Rule
    val benchmarkRule = MacrobenchmarkRule()

    @Test
    fun startUpCompilationModeWithoutBaseline() {
        startup(CompilationMode.None())
    }

    fun startup(mode: CompilationMode) = benchmarkRule.measureRepeated(
        packageName = globalPackageName, //:app package name
        metrics = listOf(StartupTimingMetric()),
        iterations = 1,
        startupMode = StartupMode.COLD,
        compilationMode = mode,
    ) {
        pressHome()
        startActivityAndWait() // library itself captures the startup time
        ApiClient.create()
        val buttonObject =
            device.findObject(By.res(loginPackageName,"bt_login")) // return null object , Activity = MainActivity, Fragment = LoginFragment
        buttonObject.click()
    }

}

inside presenation I have a button bt_login and I want to tap it but I am unable to get that.
I tried layout inspector and checked the layout Its available with same id.
I tried espresso and generated test with onView(withId(R.id.bt_login)).perform(click()) //this works
I am unable to find a object, is it possible to list all objects available in present screen? or how to find it properly?
I tried By.res() , By.text() , UiSelector 
But alll returned same null object
